# Can the pixel transfer format change when uploading texture data via glTexSubImage?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

I'm facing a situation where, for the sake of compatibility, first I allocate a texture's storage, then I upload texture data into it. The idea is to keep the code path similar depending on whether immutable storage is supported or not supported.

In the absence of immutable storage, the storage gets allocated via a `glTexImage2D` call (with a NULL data pointer, no pixel unpack buffer bound), for instance like this:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,
             GL_RGBA,                           
             width, height, 0,
             GL_RGBA,                           
             GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
             0);
```

After this, the actual data gets uploaded:

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                width, height,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                data);
```

---

The problem is: **at upload time, can the pixel transfer format be different from the one specified when allocating the storage?** Some drivers think yes, some drivers (notably: ANGLE) think not.

In other words, is then this call supposed to worK?

```
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0,
                width, height,
                GL_RGBA,
                GL_FLOAT, // <-- DIFFERENT
                data);
```

To my interpretation of the OpenGL 4.5 specification, yes. Not only `glTexSubImage2D` is supposed to work with immutable textures (and in the `glTexStorage` call there's no pixel transfer format specified); the 4.5 specification says in §8.6 (emphasis mine):

> TexSubImage*D and TextureSubImage*D arguments width, height, depth, format, type, and data match the corresponding arguments to the corresponding TexImage*D command (where those arguments exist), meaning that **they accept the same values**, and have the same meanings.

To me that means "they accept the same set of values" (any value amongst the valid ones), and not "they accept the very same value passed to `glTexImage*D`".

In the OpenGL ES 2.0 specification the wording is slightly different:

> TexSubImage2D arguments width, height, format, type, and data match the corresponding arguments to TexImage2D, meaning that they are specified using the same values, and have the same meanings.

Again, to me, this should not imply that the pixel transfer format must match, only that the accepted values are from within the same set.

---

So, is my interpretation correct?

---

**ADDENDUM**.

I've been digging into the OpenGL man pages. Now of course they're not normative (the specification is), but there's a significant difference between the ES2/3 man pages and the OpenGL 4.5 one:

- GLES 2: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml
- GLES 3: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml
- GL 4.5: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml

Note that in the GLES3 cases there's this wording: "internalFormat may be one of the unsized (base) internal formats shown, together with valid format and type combinations", strongly implying that the indeed the triple is used to allocate the storage.

<sub>However, GLES3 also has immutable storage out-of-the-box, so that makes no sense...</sub>

But anyhow that makes my call to `glTexImage2D` perfectly legal. Then, the problematic call becomes `glTexSubImage2D`:

- GLES 2: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexSubImage2D.xml
- GLES 3: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexSubImage2D.xhtml

In there, the only error condition referencing the internal format is this in GLES 2:

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if the texture array has not been defined by a previous `glTexImage2D` or `glCopyTexImage2D` operation whose *internalformat* matches the *format* of `glTexSubImage2D`.

And this in GLES 3:

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if the combination of *internalFormat* of the previously specified texture array, *format* and *type* is not valid. See `glTexImage2D`.

Which again means my interpretation is right: the combination of format + type passed to `glTexSubImage2D`, plus the internal format passed to `glTexImage2D`, is indeed a valid combination listed in the `glTexImage2D` doc.

Answer (score 2):

> So, is my interpretation correct?

In one word: Yes. It's called *internal format* and *pixel data format* for a reason. ANGLE is an emulation of OpenGL-ES and hence follows the specification and behavior as specified for that. Which is consistent with your observation.

Comment: Sorry, what's "consistent" with what? I'm interpreting the OpenGL ES 2.0 spec the same way I'm interpreting the OpenGL 4.5 -- "using the same values" meaning "accepting the values from the same set". So ANGLE behaviour would be at fault here.

Comment: @peppe: I've to re-read the ES specification carefully on that part.

Comment: Added some bits to the original post.

Comment: @peppe: OpenGL ES is different from desktop GL in that it does not support data conversion during pixel transfer. Your internal format must match the pixel data format, this is why there are [entire tables dedicated to matching formats](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) in the ES manual pages. It is all down to simplifying the implementation in ES, and converting image formats during pixel transfer adds a lot of unnecessary complication that is apparently only worthwhile in desktop GL ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: This is how I'd have interpreted the wording of the ES spec as well in the first place.

Comment: But the internal format does match the external format, it's just the external type that changes between the two calls, as I added to my post.

Comment: @peppe: After allocating the texture with glTexImage or glTexStorage the internal format is fixed. If your internal format at allocation is based on OpenGL-ES choosing from data format GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE and then you upload from a GL_FLOAT, things will not work. You have to use an explicit internal format type instead. GL_RGBA gives some leeway.

Comment: I understand the reasoning, however it's not in the spec, is it? :)